# How to access view model data in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model, viewmodel

In my html, I use Model.Subcontract.company

How can I reference that data in my jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value to an html element and then access it via jquery.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%= Model.Subcontract.Company %>" id="hidData" name="hidData" />

$("#hidData").val();
```

Comment: I wound up doing it this way.  Mine was starting to get cumbersome as I got further into it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an effective way to reference the model as an object in jQuery:

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
```

If you want to avoid the harmless, intellisense error:

```
var model = [@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it like this:

```
"<%= Model.Subcontract.company %>"
```

It's always easier to figure it out after you've given up and asked the question!

Comment: As long as you write the JavaScript inside the View file it will work, but in the future if you put all the JavaScript in a separate .js file it ll stop working, as the .js extensions are not processed by the IIS pipeline, it wont parse the "<% %>" tags anymore unless you do some hacks to the IIS.